# apt-key configuration error

Tags: apt, nvidia, updates, proxy, cuda

I am trying to install cuda10.1 on ubuntu18.04 following this guide: https://medium.com/@exesse/cuda-10-1-installation-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-d04f89287130. The following command fails with connection timed out error.

`sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys  http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub`

I tried running with `-E` after exporting proxies, same issue. I also tried the following:

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver-options http-proxy=http:*.*.*.*:**** --fetch-keys  http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub`

but it fails with the following configuration error:

> gpg: requesting key from 'http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub'
> gpg: WARNING: unable to fetch URI http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub: Configuration error

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The following command you'd mentioned in your answer should work perfectly:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver-options http-proxy=http:*.*.*.*:**** --fetch-keys  http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
```

If it does not work then you might need to do the following steps (which helped me):

Write on the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

Paste the following at the end:

```
export http_proxy="http://example.proxy.server:8080"
export https_proxy="https://example.proxy.server:8080"
export no_proxy="localhost.127.0.0.1,::1,localhost"
```

Then save and exit (`ctrl+x`, `y`, and `enter`).

Again, write the following on the terminal:

```
nano ~/.profile
```

Then paste in the same thing as above, and save and exit (`ctrl+x`, `y`, and `enter`):

```
export http_proxy="http://example.proxy.server:8080"
export https_proxy="https://example.proxy.server:8080"
export no_proxy="localhost.127.0.0.1,::1,localhost"
```

Then, maybe you could try this command again:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver-options http-proxy=http:*.*.*.*:**** --fetch-keys  http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
```

You have to be very careful to see that there's no typo in the HTTP/HTTPS proxy, otherwise you'd get the same error you're facing.

Reference:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cq4TYmogon0&lc=UgyOQytoh3iCnKaFXOl4AaABAg.9Pa3t0hfQkQ9Pa4LQoCSdJ